# Layout display incorrectly in android 5.0

Tags: android, android-layout

I created which layout file have 1 radioGroup ( 3 radio button ) and 1 editText. I always get a issue same as below picture after few minutes using app. I don't know root cause for this issue. I tested on android 4.4.2 and it worked well.

[image: Error layout]
[image: normal layout]

XML Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/food_instructions"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/layout_instruction_raido_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/layout_instruction_raido_before_food"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/before_food" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/layout_instruction_raido_with_food"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/with_food" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/layout_instruction_raido_after_food"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/after_food" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/layout_instruction_raido_no_food"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_food_instructions" />
</RadioGroup>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/layout_instruction_free_text"
    android:labelFor="@+id/layout_instruction_free_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text">
</EditText>
```

Do you have any advice for this issue?
Thanks

Comment: It seems OK. Have you tried to remove `android:ems="10"` and `android:labelFor="@+id/layout_instruction_free_text"`?

Comment: @Nguyen DoanTung: I removed them but issue is existing. I don't think that is root cause. thank Tung

Comment: Are you using any appcompat libraries?

Comment: @hidro: I'm using android-support-v4 and support-v13 libs

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with auto complete text view before, could be a known appcompat bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77742

Comment: @hirdo:  Exactly, my previous layout have auto complete text view. when I switch them, issue is happened. Do you have any suggestion to work around?